# Restore User or Backup exec settings after demoting

Tags: backupexec, active-directory, user-accounts, domain-controller

Just don't mess with a server when you're not feeling focused, because you can end up something like i did:

I have a server (WS2003 R2) which acts as backup server (backup exec 2010). We needed a domain for Cluster services, so we decided to try with this server as DC. After promoting, the local accounts became domain accounts. Then, we changed our mind and in a hothead move, we demoted the server.

Then i saw i had lost all local accounts, and i tried to recreated them.
Now, i'm not able to start the services (the dependency service or group failed to start) and i don't even know which account was used as log on service... (i've tried with all the old ones, but none works).

Anyways of getting the user back (i dont see anything in the registry, nor folders, but there is a few unknown accounts), or the backup exec settings?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

when you recreated the services for Backup Exec make sure they are running as the following:

•Backup Exec Agent Browser server: start up type - Automatic and logon as Domain\Username
•Backup Exec Job Engine Service: start up type - Automatic and logon as Domain\Username
•Backup Exec Server Service: start up type - Automatic and logon as Domain\Username
•Backup Exec Device and Media service: start up type - Automatic and logon as Domain\Username
•Backup Exec Remote Agent servicestart up type - Automatic and logon as local system account
•SQL Server (BKUPEXEC) - Automatic startup and log on as Local System account
then verify the password by going to properties click on Log on and re enter the password of the 'Username" (same as the System Default Logon for BackupExec)

Try a repair install of Backup Exec

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an user with enough permissions to run a backup.

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH136148
http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH184449
http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO99216#v53937162
http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH161715

All these articles helped. But the final solution was having the sql user as dbo for every database, not only the BEDB.